# search contents in php files in Windows 7

Tags: php, windows

I have spent a long time looking for a way to search a phrase across some of my php files in Windows 7.

Things I have done include:

- enabling “Always search file names and contents” in Windows Explorer;
- adding php in the list of “Index properties and File Contents to enable content search” in Indexing Options;
- making sure the directory is indexed;
- making sure I have the permission to that directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs).

What else should I try?  Is that even possible to do that in Windows 7?  If not, I’ll have to install Cygwin, which I am reluctant to do now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698038/windows-recursive-grep-command-line

Comment: Did you try this? : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30

Comment: an IDE with a search function, like eclipse is an idea. or  a stand alone search application (i use astroGrep and 'search and replace' both windows apps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you attempting to search the contents of each of the .php files themselves?

Or are you searching for a phrase in filenames with the corresponding .php file extension?

If your goal is the former, the following text editors can easily "Find all in open files" and even "Find all in folder(s)":

- http://www.sublimetext.com/
- http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

If what you're looking for is a command line option, the `findstr` command should serve you just fine. More information on findstr [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).

If you're attempting to do the latter, then the link provided by Dany Caissy looks like it'll have just what you're looking for.

Comment: The method in Dany Caissy's link didn't work for me.  The findstr command is exactly what I want.  Thanks, everyone, particularly Justice Cassel.

Comment: notepad++ did the trick (especially since its my editor of choice -  no need to install and test)  UPVOTED! :)

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Unix has a `grep` command line utility for doing exactly what you want. If the built-in Win7 search/explorer capabilities don't do what you want, perhaps one of these links for third-party windows equivalents to grep:

[Windows-equiv grep command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698038/windows-recursive-grep-command-line)

[Using Windows7 built-in `findstr` from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/300815/command-prompt-msdos-windows-7-grep-equivalent)

Note that Justice Cassel's answer has an excellent solution (search in all open files - +1 Justice), if you have your PHP files open in Notepad++. If you aren't using that NP++ for programming, you really should check it out. The FTP plugin (which automatically uploads a file every time you save it) is worth its weight, plus a dump truck, in gold.

Answer (score 0):

In tools > folder options > search, you need to tick the box for always search file content.

Then when searching for a phrase e.g. "cats and dogs" you need to type the following in the search box

```
content:(~="cats and dogs").
```