# MYSQL - How to find files which send queries to database

Tags: mysql

I can't find informations about name of files e.g. "index.php" which using queries to databases,
I need to find which file modify data in databases on machine where also is database:)

This file can use a script php mysql query, but I'm not sure, maybe not :/

There is any options to get list all such files on my system?

System is windows server 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[search contents in php files in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201400/search-contents-in-php-files-in-windows-7)

```
 the following text editors can easily "Find all in open files" and even "Find all in folder(s)":

http://www.sublimetext.com/
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/
```

You just need to search sql keywords like UPDATE DELETE or CREATE with text editors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm using notepad++ and have a lot of files in many directories, and name of table which is modify e.g. "table_name" I can't find in supposed folders. I need avoid searching in whole system with 1TB disc:)

Comment: Make a search on all php files on your computer and open all php files with notepad++