# Searching recursively one string on windows OS

Tags: windows-7, findstr

I want to search one string e.g. "main" in my project on windows OS recursively. I searched that and find a solution [Windows recursive grep command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698038/windows-recursive-grep-command-line)

I applied same with two different approach, and result is not as expected.

e.g. my approach

```
findstr /S "main" *.cpp
```

but when I choose

```
findstr /S "int main" *.cpp
```

I am not getting only my main function.
What is the difference between these two approaches? is it wrong to provide strings with space?

Comment: Why this is tagged to `C++` ?

Comment: @P0W.. Actually I am using C++ files in my project. If it is not worth tag I can remove it.

Comment: @Krishna and its already removed !

Comment: This is off topic. `findstr` is not _directly_ related to programming and the fact that you are searching source files is IMHO irrelevant. This question would be better served on SuperUser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows recursive grep command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698038/windows-recursive-grep-command-line). The accepted answer of the question you linked to answers your questions as well.

Comment: @P0W... actually I dont know we have `findstr` tag. Thanks P0W.. Thanks @Mat

Comment: @Oswald... Just want to know one thing.. can we provide search strings with space like "int main"? is it valid?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, so every question about the Unix command line is off-topic too? Interesting.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is because `findstr` takes a *set of strings to search for*. To actually match the string `int main` you have to use the `/C` option:

```
findstr /s /C:"int main" *.cpp
```

whereas your variant gives you every line with either `int` or `main`.

Comment: why `\s` instead of `\S`?

Answer (score 4):

Kind of late to the party here,
but if you use

```
findstr /S "int.main" *.cpp
```

it will treat the dot as a wild card,
which matches a space, and as long as you 
don't mind some superfluous matches (which are unlikely in this case)
it will work fine for you.

I use that, having not known about the /C: option before reading the answers above.