# laravel(artisan) stuck on one error no matter the command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

No matter what command I enter I get the error

"Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.products' doesn't exist

I tried

```
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan migrate
```

and other artisan commands and they all return the above mentioned error. Anyone has idea how to solve this

Comment: give your migration code

Comment: `grep -R 'database.products' app/*` on your command line will help you find out where it's referenced.

Comment: i'm using windows

Comment: Oh, sure, make things difficult. Looks like `findstr` should work instead. Try `findstr /S /C:"database.products" app/` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698038/windows-recursive-grep-command-line))

Comment: @aynber In Laravel `database.products` is unlikely to appear in the code anywhere. Laravel would query that table via something like `Product::all()` or `Product::where()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your Service Providers (particularly the `boot` method), make sure none of them are querying models or tables, unless those statements are happening in a closure.  This includes any 3rd party providers.

One of the common scenarios is a `view()->share(...)` that is querying the database.

Comment: jup it was a boot method

Answer (score 2):

This means you have an error somewhere in your code. You should check all controllers and other classes where you're trying to work with `products` table. Fix the problem and all `artisan` commands will work fine.